# Trying to get all the text to the left of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a function that returns some values and uses STUFF to put them all in one column.

Some of the results contain:

```
Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ... and lots of stuff in here. />
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to remove the entire:

```
<?xml /> tag and all of its inner content.
```

The problem is, sometimes it ends up in different parts of the results per/row basis.

So I've tried CHARINDEX, LEFT, Splits...

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you have more than one `<?xml ... />` substring in a field?

Comment: Can you have `<?xml` **without** matching `/>` and visa versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @String = 'Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ......... />'


SELECT LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX('<?xml',@String)-1) Val
```

Results:

```
╔══════════════════════════════╗
║             Val              ║
╠══════════════════════════════╣
║ Something, something else, ? ║
╚══════════════════════════════╝
```

**UPDATE**

Well, the new requirement is tricky, the really hard part would be founding where exactly does your XML tag ends. Assuming a very simple scenario where only one XML tag exists and there are no previous `/>` in your string, then you could do this:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @String = 'Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ......... /> hello'


SELECT STUFF(@String,CHARINDEX('<?xml',@String),CHARINDEX('/>',@String)-CHARINDEX('<?xml',@String)+2,'') Val
```

Results:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║                Val                 ║
╠════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Something, something else, ? hello ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to do that, but the problem is some of the results contain important information after that xml tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(MAX) = 'Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ... and lots of stuff in here. />, something else yet'
DECLARE @StartOfXml INT = PATINDEX('%<?xml%', @string)
DECLARE @EndOfXml INT = PATINDEX('%/>%', @string)
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@string, 0, @StartOfXml) + 
    SUBSTRING(@string, @EndOfXml + 2, LEN(@string))
```

OR to put it all inline:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(MAX) = 'Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ... and lots of stuff in here. />, something else yet'
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@string, 0, PATINDEX('%<?xml%', @string)) + 
    SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%/>%', @string) + 2, LEN(@string))
```

The problem with this or other answers presented thus far is that depending on your XML, you could have multiple "/>" in the string.  In that case, you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(MAX) = 'Something, something else, ?<?xml version="1.0" ... and lots of stuff in here. />, something else yet'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 0, PATINDEX('%<?xml%', @string)) + 
       SUBSTRING(@string, (LEN(@string) - PATINDEX('%>/%', REVERSE(@string))) + 2, LEN(@string))
```

The last solution assumes that the final closing tag to your XML is the last occurrence of the string: "/>".  Hope one of these helps!